# Eigenvalues -prove or refute

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hey guys,
I need to prove or refute that once given an eigenvalue t of a matrix AB and B is invertible,

so t is also eigenvalue of A.

I believe it's not true, but sadly beliefs are not enough in math  : )

Thank you.

Comment: If you believe it's not true, you should try to come up with a counterexample. Here's a hint: try the simplest thing that could possibly work—let $A = [a]$ and $B = [b]$ be $1\times 1$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=B^{-1}$, then $t=1$. Clearly there are invertible matrices $B$ which don't have $1$ as an  eigenvalue.

Comment: If A=B^-1, Do A and B have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: No, if $\{ \lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_n \}$ is the set of  eigenvalues of $B$, then $\{ 1/\lambda_1, \dots , 1/\lambda_n \}$ is the set of eigenvalues of $B^{-1}$.

Comment: I see, and from this we get that 1 cannot be a eigenvalue of A also. Thanks.